# Cannot find method 'value()' in the @Qualifier annotation

Tags: java, spring, backend, spring-annotations

Over here I get an error saying qualifier cannot find method value in it where I can pass a name:

```java
@Qualifier("abstractLanguageService")
public abstract class Ae implements Le {
    // ...
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the versions, I am using amazon correto 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the import of the annotation ? `javax.inject.Qualifier` don't have a `value()` method but spring'ones have.